# Multiple string replacement, decimals to quarters

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I want to replace `.00` with `-Q1`, `.25` with `-Q2`, `.50` with `-Q3`, and `.75` with `-Q4` as given below. However, my code is not working as expected. Any hints?

```
library(tidyverse)

dt1 <- 
  tibble(Date = c(2015.00, 2015.25, 2015.50, 2015.75))

dt1
# A tibble: 4 x 1
   Date
  <dbl>
1 2015 
2 2015.
3 2016.
4 2016.

dt1 %>% 
  pull(Date)

[1] 2015.00 2015.25 2015.50 2015.75

dt1 %>% 
  mutate(Date1 = str_replace_all(string = Date, pattern = c(".00" = "-Q1", ".25" = "-Q2", ".50" = "-Q3", ".75" = "-Q4")))

# A tidytable: 4 × 2
   Date Date1  
  <dbl> <chr>  
1 2015  2015   
2 2015. 2015-Q2
3 2016. 2015.5 
4 2016. 2015-Q4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There also is a zoo-function for that:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

dt1 <- 
  tibble(Date = c(2015.00, 2015.25, 2015.50, 2015.75))

dt1 %>%
  mutate(Date1 = format.yearqtr(Date, format = "%Y.Q%q") )

# Date Date1  
# <dbl> <chr>  
# 1 2015  2015.Q1
# 2 2015. 2015.Q2
# 3 2016. 2015.Q3
# 4 2016. 2015.Q4
```

Answer (score 3):

You may also use integer division `%/%` and modulo division `%%` simultaneously

```
paste0(dt1$Date %/% 1, '-Q',(dt1$Date %% 1)*4 +1)

[1] "2015-Q1" "2015-Q2" "2015-Q3" "2015-Q4"
```

Thus, using it in piped syntax as

```
dt1 %>%
  mutate(date1 = paste0(Date %/% 1, '-Q',(Date %% 1)*4 +1))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
   Date date1  
  <dbl> <chr>  
1 2015  2015-Q1
2 2015. 2015-Q2
3 2016. 2015-Q3
4 2016. 2015-Q4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vec <- c("00" = "-Q1", "25" = "-Q2", "50" = "-Q3", "75" = "-Q4")
dt1 %>%
  mutate(new = paste0(Date %/% 1, vec[sprintf("%02d", Date %% 1 * 100)]))

   Date new    
  <dbl> <chr>  
1 2015  2015-Q1
2 2015. 2015-Q2
3 2016. 2015-Q3
4 2016. 2015-Q4
```

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu for your answer and a solution.

Comment: Onyambu, just for my knowledge, can we use `switch` here?

Comment: @AnilGoyal yes, although that will require you to write a function

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2):

here is a quick fix:

```
 dt1 %>% 
  mutate(Date1 = str_replace_all(format(Date, nsmall = 2), 
                pattern = c(".00" = "-Q1", ".25" = "-Q2", ".50" = "-Q3", ".75" = "-Q4")))
```

The problem is that `2015.00` is first transformed to character at which point it becomes `2015`. Therefore, the string replacement fails.
You can see this, by trying `as.character(2015.00)`.

However, this can easily be fixed by using `format` to format the number first.

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)


dt1 <- 
    as.character(c(2015.00, 2015.25, 2015.50, 2015.75))


dt1 <- if_else(str_detect(dt1, '\\.', negate = TRUE),
               paste0(dt1, '.00'), #If condition TRUE
               dt1) #if condition FALSE


value_before <- c("\\.00","\\.25","\\.5","\\.75" )
value_after  <- c("-Q1", "-Q2","-Q3", "-Q4")

tibble(Date = str_replace(dt1, value_before, value_after))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   Date   
#>   <chr>  
#> 1 2015-Q1
#> 2 2015-Q2
#> 3 2015-Q3
#> 4 2015-Q4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `dyplr` and `tidyr`:

1. Prepare decimals for further process with `format`
2. `separate` and `mutate` with `-Q1-Q4`
3. `unite`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dt1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = format(round(Date, digits=2), nsmall = 2)) %>% 
  separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Quarter"), remove=FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Quarter = recode(Quarter, "00" = "-Q1", "25" = "-Q2", "50" = "-Q3", "75" = "-Q4")) %>% 
  unite("new", Year:Quarter, sep = "")
```

Output:

```
  Date    new    
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 2015.00 2015-Q1
2 2015.25 2015-Q2
3 2015.50 2015-Q3
4 2015.75 2015-Q4
```